# Can't set Emacs Speedbar buffer display mode

Tags: emacs24, emacs-ecb, emacs-speedbar

I often work with differents active buffer on emacs like :

- source files
- SQL buffer
- shell buffer

I try to get speedbar always display buffer mode but I can't find any option that can load this display when emacs is started (default is file mode), and keep it during all session.

I also tried ecb history window that can display opened/recently closed edit buffers but there's no way to make it display specials buffers like SQL or shell.

How can I customize emacs to get this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is really old, but I'm going to answer it for anyone searching out there. I did this with a mode hook:

```
;; Start Sr-Speedbar in buffer mode by default
(add-hook 'speedbar-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (speedbar-change-initial-expansion-list "quick buffers")))
```